# How to add cocoapods to existing workspace not project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am working on a project which is composed of three other projects in a workspace. I want to use CocoaPods to manage my dependecies in the workspace, but CocoaPods always creates its own workspace with only one addtional project. What I want to do is to add CocoaPods project to the workspace that already exists. Is there any simple way to achive that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify a workspace in your podfile.

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace'
```

Please consult this link for more info:
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#workspace

Answer (score 52):

In terminal go to directory with your xcworkspace-file.

`$ touch Podfile`

then in Podfile :

```
workspace 'YourWorkspace'

target 'YourProjectName' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    pod 'your pod' 
    project 'Path to your Project in your workspace'
end
```

`$ pod install`

Comment: why do you add an answer to an old question with an accepted answer, which is almost the same as your answer?

Comment: It has more details. The old answer doesn't help me in my search

Comment: A mix between this answer and https://medium.com/@youvalv/cocoapods-for-an-existing-multi-project-workspace-1fb73f46fede helped me to build this. 
Beware though, once `pod install` has been run, clean the project and relaunch XCode. Sometimes it fails updating dependencies. Thanks mate

Comment: The path in the `project` should **not** begin with "/". For me this worked: `project 'pathTo/MyProject'` but this didn't: `project '/pathTo/MyProject'`.