# Add cocoapods to existing ones?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

I have a workspace with one library code downloaded via podfile. I had no possibility to change its functionality via protocols so I edited its code.

Now I need to add another library to my project but how to do it and prevent "undo" my own changes to the first library?

[My question is not a duplicate of this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295833/how-to-add-cocoapods-project-to-already-existing-workspace) In that question uses asks how to merge 2 projects with their own workspaces. But I have one project with a workspace and a separate library.

Comment: you would have to move the code of the library that you has modified to the project, outside of the cocoapods project. Or if you think that your changes could be of "general interest" try pushing them to the "official" repo of the library

Comment: You didn't understand me. I got a code of a library via cocoapods. Then I edited this code in my local copy. NOTE: I can't commit this code to the official repository because of both privacy and essence of these changes (font type, shadow, color and etc. which are not provided via external protocols). Now I need to get another library from another place and I don't want to delete my current changes.

Comment: you tried opening de podfile, delete the pod you don't want to modify, add the new pod, and pod install. This should do the trick

Comment: @user3798020 that is exactly what I understand. Move the code of the library that you modify to your project, _outside_ of cocoapods and remove the dependency from the cocoapods file

Comment: The first library is coreplot. It is (or was) impossible to add it as simply sources. I can try to import as sources only further libraries. And it is not very well