# Integrate/Install cocoapods to existing xcode project, objective-c or swift

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was looking for integrating cocoapods to my existing xcode projects.

I found these few post but they are based on issue instead my problem.

[not able to acess installed pods framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585168/integrating-cocoapod-to-existing-project)

[How to add cocoapods to existing workspace not project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295833/how-to-add-cocoapods-project-to-already-existing-workspace) (this one is for work-space not project)

[Making a CocoaPod from an existing Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445691/making-a-cocoapod-from-an-existing-xcode-project) (this one is more on integrating swift with objective c project)

So I spending quality time i did for my project.
I am sharing step by step integration in my answer post.

please feel free to suggest and improvement.

happy to learn and share

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Install CocoaPods on System**

Step.1 Open Terminal and enter the following command:

> sudo gem install cocoapods

---

**Create Podfile for Project**

Step.2 now you need to close Xcode.

Open Terminal at project's root folder

Step.3 Next, enter below command to create podfile:

> pod init

---

**Edit podfile**

*Note*: Make sure we will edit podfile with Xcode not TextEdit etc.

Step.4 Type this command to open the Podfile using Xcode for editing:

> open -a Xcode Podfile

Step.5 update pode file as shown below screenshot, save and close.

[image]

**Install lib/framework**

Now we have added our required lib/framework pod command

```
pod 'SwiftForms'
```

let's go for install

Step.5 Enter the following command in Terminal and hit Enter

pod install

Result screen

[image]

Thats it!! we have done.

**Open Project with pods**

Now go to the project folder,we can see that CocoaPods created a new project_name.xcworkspace file and a Pods folder.

open project_name.xcworkspace with xcode

your project structure should look like

[image]

Comment: Till now top of all answer to install pod file from initial, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238)

Comment: Why is it important to use Xcode to edit the podfile?